# CSS How do you override the custom font family set in the all selector?

Tags: css, fonts, font-family

I downloaded two custom fonts for my website, and I am trying to make one of them the default font for almost everywhere in the website, and the other one for some certain areas. So my code look something like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <nav>
        <ul className="Navbar">
          <li className="link1"><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
          <li className="link2"><Link to="/AboutMe">AboutMe</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path="/AboutMe" element={<AboutMe />}/>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat-VariableFont_wght';
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'BowlbyOneSC-Regular';
    src: url('../fonts/BowlbyOneSC-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');   
    font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat-VariableFont_wght';
    src: url('../fonts/Montserrat-VariableFont_wght.ttf') format('truetype');
}

.link1{
    font-family: 'BowlbyOneSC-Regular';
}
```

Both link1 and link2 are now in the font of `Montserrat-VariableFont_wght`, and when I remove `font-family: 'Montserrat-VariableFont_wght';`from the * selector. Link1 will then be `BowlbyOneSC-Regular` and then link2 become some random default font provided by browser, which is not what I want. So, how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the

```css
.link1 {
    font-family: 'BowlbyOneSC-Regular' !important;
}
```

notice `! important` this will override the link1 css and link2 will be default one defined.

You can do something like a utility class with the font face. I usually do .ff-roboto .ff-arial and implement font family there.

```css
.ff-BowlbyOneSC' {
   font-family: 'BowlbyOneSC-Regular';
}
```

now you can use link2 as ff-BowlbyOneSC

```html
<li className="link2 ff-BowlbyOneSC"><Link to="/AboutMe">AboutMe</Link></li>
```

`* is not a good way of defining css property` as it apply this font family to all the html element.

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat-VariableFont_wght';
}
```

you can also see I have removed regular from the name. It means you can also have font weight related utility functions like `.fw-300` or `fw-bold` `fw-black` this how you can create reusable classes.

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?

Comment: @humanbean adding font family in body will help in getting resolving the random font issue.

Comment: but if you want to target elements in the body of an HTML page, it makes no difference (to **those** elements) if you target them using `*` or `body`.  Clearly the problem lies elsewhere. Also, OP did not ask for "good ways of defining CSS properties"; they asked for a solution.

Comment: @humanbean gotcha. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: @ShashankShandilya Thanks for your help! I've moved my font-family declaration to the body. But somehow I didn't even need the ```!important``` and it still works. So, one more 'noob-y' question: Why is that the overriding doesn't work when the font family is defined in ```*``` selector but it works when it's in the body?

Comment: * is a selector in css which applies to all the html elements it means it applies to all html elements explicitly  there is no room for adding another font family for an element. Every html element has properties that are inherited from the parent or from the body if any property is explicitly mentioned you have no room for adding another property. the only option is to override with !important